# Special sized towel rack brackets needed - do they exist?

Tags: bathroom, walls, drill, brackets

I'm trying to replace my bathroom towel racks, without re-drilling holes in the wall. The previous rack's holes are wider apart than all the standard holes I'm finding in stores, so I'm not finding any brackets that fit the holes in my walls. Where can I find more specific sizes?

Comment: There are no "standard holes"! There are hundreds (thousands, millions?) of manufacturers of towel bars and racks, all of them do it their own way. Just buy the ones you like best and resign yourself to the fact that you will need to patch and paint the old holes and properly anchor the new unit(s).

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a towel bar to your liking that has the bar as a separate piece, longer than the spacing you need. Cut the bar to the length you need and install.

I have had to cut the bar on occasion when the space was too small for the bar on the wall, so I made it shorter.The same idea should work for you.